# How to set Schema name using Dapper.SimpleCrud?

Tags: dapper, dapper-simplecrud

I am using Dapper.SimpleCrud. Does anyone know how to set the schema name for a table? I have looked through the documentation but I have not found anything relating to setting or changing the schema name.

```
public class doc_info
{
    public int doc_info_id { get; set; }
    public int app_info_id { get; set; }
    public string doc_name { get; set; }
    public string file_loc { get; set; }
    public string doc_type { get; set; }
    public string doc_scope { get; set; }
    public int doc_order { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was old request raised [here on GitHub](https://github.com/ericdc1/Dapper.SimpleCRUD/issues/6):

> A work around is to provide a TableAttribute on the class in this fashion:
>
> `[Table("Schema].[Table")]`

The feature was included as stated [here on GitHub](https://github.com/ericdc1/Dapper.SimpleCRUD/pull/9):

> See the tests: https://github.com/ericdc1/Dapper.SimpleCRUD/blob/master/Dapper.SimpleCRUDTests/Tests.cs#L83
>
> ```
> [Table("CarLog", Schema = "Log")]
> public class CarLog
> {
>     public int Id { get; set; }
>     public string LogNotes { get; set; }
> }
>
> public void TestInsertIntoDifferentSchema()
> {
>     using (var connection = GetOpenConnection())
>     {
>         var id = connection.Insert(new CarLog { LogNotes = "blah blah blah" });
>         id.IsEqualTo(1);
>         connection.Delete<CarLog>(id);
>      }
> }
> ```

Class `TableAttribute` have a property `Schema`:

> ```
> [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
> public class TableAttribute : Attribute
> {
>     public TableAttribute(string tableName);
>
>   //
>     // Summary:
>     //     Name of the table
>     public string Name { get; }
>     //
>     // Summary:
>     //     Name of the schema
>     public string Schema { get; set; }
> }
> ```

You should set this `TableAttribute.Schema` property while decorating Entity/POCO with `Table` attribute. Decorate your Entity/POCO class with `[Table("YourTableName", Schema = "YourSchema")]`.

Comment: Don't know what I'm doing wrong.
Neither 
[Table("[Zld_File_Data]", Schema = "[DI]")] nor 
[Table("Zld_File_Data", Schema = "DI")] nor
[Table("DI].[Zld_File_Data")]
worked.

Workaround was to use [Table("[DI].[Zld_File_Data]")] (i.e. setting the Name property to a single string which included the schema.